# Ошибка при запуске Visual Studio-2015 (0xc06d007e)

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2015

при запуске выдаёт эту ошибку

devenv.exe - Ошибка приложения
 Исключение неизвестное программное исключение (0xc06d007e) в приложении по адресу 0x74bfc52f.

В журнале событии у VS две ошибки

1) источник : Application erorr, код события : 1000

Имя сбойного приложения: devenv.exe, версия: 14.0.25123.0, отметка времени: 0x56f22f32
Имя сбойного модуля: KERNELBASE.dll, версия: 6.1.7601.19135, отметка времени 0x56a1c79e
Код исключения: 0xc06d007e
Смещение ошибки: 0x0000c52f
Идентификатор сбойного процесса: 0xe6c
Время запуска сбойного приложения: 0x01d3e146ae3fd9b0
Путь сбойного приложения: C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\Common7\IDE\devenv.exe
Путь сбойного модуля: C:\Windows\syswow64\KERNELBASE.dll
Код отчета: ec574589-4d39-11e8-b4cd-020351076464

2) источник : .Net Runtime, код события : 1026

Приложение: devenv.exe
Версия платформы: v4.0.30319
Описание. Процесс был завершен из-за необработанного исключения.
Сведения об исключении: код исключения c06d007e, адрес исключения 767BC52F

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Помогло обновление .Net Frameworka были версии до 4.6.1 установил 4.7

Comment: и мне кстати помогло про аналогичной проблеме, обновление .Net Frameworka были версии до 4.5 установил 4.7